# Window Behavior in Flash Catalyst

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, behavior, flashcatalyst

I'm trying to do a little flash site but i'm having some problems.
As you can see it here:
http://alexandracardoso.deviantart.com/gallery/?catpath=scraps#/d56idb3

When I open the right window clicking in the tab on the right, I would like that when I open the left one by clicking in the tab, the right one would close and open the left one.
But I'm unable to do that.

I thought and tried using if statement to help me but it doesn't work.

Someone can help me and say how I can make the behavior of opening one little window make the other one disappear.

Comment: This is another very confusing question, from the link I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here, could you specify the labels for the tabs you're talking about instead of just in relative terms (or do they have icons, where are they located on the screen), show the code you've tried.

Comment: understood, but reading the question it's very confusing what you're asking.  In playing with the flash content a bit I think I see what you're saying when you click the far right button it's then not allowing you to click the far left button to return.  If you don't mind posting your FLA I can likely fix this pretty quickly it shouldn't be all too complicated.

Comment: @Dason  Sorry about that, english isn't my language.
 
Well, i didn't do much, what i only did in flash was open a tab and close it when clicking in it. 
There's a tween to open the tab, to close it i switched the tab button with other one. (the 2 buttons are inside the same movie clip so the seem like one).

But here's the code, hope it helps.
www.mediafire.com/?35d1wbvjhscbpnc

Comment: Hope this helps you. i think i upload it correctly in my latest comment

Comment: Hey @Rasec Noir, your project isn't actually actionscript 3 it's using actionscript 1/2 is this your intenetion because AS3 would make this much easier. You can simply dispatch an event when the button's are clicked and listen for the event on the stage then animate the appropriate panels.

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry, my boyfriend dont understand flash to much (he wrote that post).
My problem? Well... I have those tabs, when I click them I open them, right? But when I open first the left one and then the right one, I cant see the content of right one cause the left is on top. So what I need is something that say to flash that the last tab I open will be on the top. That's possible with AS2? Cause it's a project for my school, but we didnt learn AS3.
And here is my flash program (not all things, just the part Im freaking out).
Ah, another thing, I dont understand too much of flash cause it's a new subject in my school, sorry about that.
Thanks so much!

http://www.mediafire.com/?35d1wbvjhscbpnc